# Create audio buffer from application's audio interface

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

Using PortAudio, how can I access running applications' audio interface so that I can capture the audio they produce in real time? The goal would be then to send this audio as UDP packet to a server.

I've had a look at [PortAudio's code samples](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/group__examples__src.html) but can't find anything similar.

**Maybe PortAudio is not the right library for me?**

I'm working mainly on Mac OS.

Comment: port audio is not platform specific, and because of that a number of features that are available on only some platforms are made unavailable.  I'd suggest including the OS that you're trying to work on for better advice.

Comment: @UKMonkey I've updated my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Core Audio does not have the sort of functionality you're looking for. Processes are sandboxed/isolated from one another.

You could probably achieve this using library injection, but there are a number of complications. OSX has added System Integrity Protection which disables injections. If you're willing to disable SIP (which is dangerous! Proceed at your own risk!) then you could try something like [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject) and intercepting the target processes' calls to Core Audio. But you'd never be able to ship something like this, since asking users to disable SIP is not reasonable.